# Mostar ArrayList dentro de otro ArrayList

Tags: arraylist

Hola que tal tengo este código que consiste en cargar una lista lista de pasajeros (clase Venta) dentro de una lista de servicios(clase Servicios) y mostrar cada servicio con la lista de pasajeros.
quisiera saber como puedo mostrar cada lista de servicios con sus respectivos pasajeros.
y poder mostrar un servicio a la vez.
las cargas de servicio y pasajeros ya las tengo hechas.
si me pueden ayudar muchas gracias.
les dejo el código con sus respectivas clases :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Practico2 
{

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Servicio> servicio=new ArrayList<Servicio>();
    ArrayList<Venta> venta=new ArrayList <Venta>(30);


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Practico2 practico= new Practico2();
        practico.menu();


    }


    //metodo menu...


    public  void cargarServicio () {

        int i=0;
        int x=0;

        do {
        i++;
        int id=i;   
        int dia,mes,anio;
        System.out.println("fecha de salida con el formato dd/mm/aaaa:");
        dia=sc.nextInt();
        mes=sc.nextInt();
        anio=sc.nextInt();
        Fecha fecha1= new Fecha(dia,mes,anio);

        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("ciudad de salida:");
        String csalida= sc.nextLine();


        System.out.println("fecha de llegada con formato dd/mm/aaaa:");
        dia=sc.nextInt();
        mes=sc.nextInt();
        anio=sc.nextInt();
        Fecha fecha2= new Fecha(dia,mes,anio);

        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("cuidad de llegada");    
        String cllegada= sc.nextLine();

        Servicio serv=new Servicio (id, fecha1,csalida,fecha2,cllegada);

        servicio.add(serv);
        System.out.println("0 seguir ingresando");
        x=sc.nextInt();

        serv.setVenta(new ArrayList<Venta>());

        }while(x==0);



    }

public  void cargarVenta(){

        int dni;
        int num;
        String nom;
        int x;

        System.out.println("numero de  servicio para agregar persona");
        num = sc.nextInt();

        num=num-1;

        System.out.println("");

        Servicio servicios = servicio.get(num);
        sc.nextLine();
        do {

            System.out.println("nombre:");
            nom= sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("documento:");
            dni=sc.nextInt();



            Venta vent = new Venta(nom,dni);
            venta.add(vent);

            servicios.agregarVenta(vent);

            System.out.println("0 seguir ingresando");
            x=sc.nextInt();

            }while(x==0);

    }
```

y les paso ademas las clases :

```
import java.util.List;

public class Servicio   {

    int id;
    Fecha Fsalida;
    String Csalida;
    Fecha Fllegada;
    String Cllegada;
    private List<Venta> venta;

    public Servicio(int id, Fecha fsalida, String csalida, Fecha fllegada, String cllegada) {

        this.id=id;
        this.Fsalida=fsalida;
        this.Csalida=csalida;
        this.Fllegada=fllegada;
        this.Cllegada=cllegada;

    }


    public void agregarVenta(Venta venta) {
        this.venta.add(venta);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
       return "id: "+id + "\n" +"Fecha de salida: "+ Fsalida + "\n"+"Ciudad de salida: "+ Csalida + "\n" + "Fecha de llegada: " +Fllegada+ "\n" +"Ciudad de llegada: " +Cllegada;
     }


    public List<Venta> getVenta() {
        return venta;
    }


    public void setVenta(List<Venta> venta) {
        this.venta = venta;
    }

}
```

```
public class Venta{

    String nombre;
    int documento;


    public Venta(String nom, int doc){


        this.nombre=nom;
        this.documento=doc;


    }


    @Override
    public String toString(){
       return "Nombre:"+nombre+"\nDNI:"+documento;
     }

}
```

y hay una clase mas de Fecha pero creo que no es necesaria ponerla .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si cada servicio tiene una lista de pasajeros asociada, entonces puedes omitir la lista de pasajeros dentro del main. Y hacer un forEach() con un iterador, o iterar con un for o un while ( la estructura de control que desees): 
En pseudocódigo sería :

```
servicios : arrayList<Servicio>
for(servicio en servicios){
print("servicio : x ");
print("lista de pasajaeros");
for(pasajero en servicio.getPasajeros(){
print(pasajero)}
}
```